# Python Requests :: How to write PHP code on server Side?

Tags: php, python, post, python-requests

I can't get the PYTHON REQUESTS module to work with my upload form

```
//Checking the request 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 //Getting the file 
 $file = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];

 //Getting the name of the file 
 $name = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];


 //Path to upload 
 $path = 'uploads/';

 //Storing the file to location
 move_uploaded_file($file,$path."/".$name);

 //displaying success message 
 echo 'success';
 }
```

The **above** was PHP side, now below is **python** side

```
url = 'http://my-url-to-above-file/index.php'
files = {'upload_file': open('1a.pdf', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
r.text
```

It should have worked with **upload_file** parameter. But it is not working with **file** also

Comment: I don't do python, but in other languages you have to set the encoding to be `multipart/form-data` in order to send the file.  Other possibilities include encoding (uuencode, base64encode, etc) and sending as  a single variable (don't forget to send mime type, etc as well!) if the file is small enough, and then decoding on the server end.

Comment: Please check the upload by hand trough chrome, and watch the networking tab during upload, and attach the post request's pay load, I think there will be missed something (so you will have to add not just the file, but some other field)